# filter by incoming ip v4 packets with tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump, filter

I want to filter with `TCPDUMP`  only incoming and ip v4 packets.

`tcpdump -i eth0 inbound and ip -w res.pcap`  give me incoming packets with ipv4 and ipv6

How can I filter by ipv4 only?

Answer (score 6):

When I specify **ip** at the end of the command, it gives me only IPv4 packages like this

```
tcpdump -i eth0 ip
```

Though I am not sure why the "inbound and ip" part in your command is not a syntax error...

Comment: its actually the word "ip" at the end. not an actual IP, which I mistakenly thought. thanks, your exact command works.